# How to assign several values to Byte array in one line (Visual Basic 6.0)

Tags: arrays, vb6, variable-assignment

I'm working out the old Visual Basic 6.0 project. I know a bit about Visual Basic but still can't feel the difference between VB6.0 and .Net.

What I try to do:

```
Private sbox() As Byte = {&H63, &H7C, &H77, ... , &H7B}
```

But VB6.0 give an error: Unknown symbol (about `{` bracket)
I can do just

```
Private sbox() As Byte
sbox = &H63
```

or

```
sbox(0) = &H63
```

But it is 255 values here! Can I assign it in one line as in .NET or I just need to make this:

```
sbox(0) = &H63
sbox(1) = &H7C
' ... 253 lines of the same code
sbox(255) = &H00
```

Comment: If your question relates to VB6 then it doesn't relate to VB.NET. Please use only applicable tags.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I thought people who know vb.net can give me a point about this task too, but ok! Thank you!

Comment: There is no compile-time syntax for this.  You could either write a function to convert a String of hex digit pairs or base64 or something to a Byte array or you could load very long ones from a custom resource compiled into your program.

Comment: @Bob77 Thank you, Bob! Can we solve this problem if `sbox` is an static array? If I will know it's size?

Comment: If you are using statically allocated arrays you have limited flexibility since you can't assign a newly manufactured array to another reference variable.  That means you'd have to copy your data into the existing preallocated array, but essentially that's just a detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one more way to solve this task:

```
Private sbox() As Byte
ReDim sbox(255)

Dim i As Integer
 For i = 0 To 255
  sbox(i) = Choose(i + 1, &H63, &H7C, _
            ..., &H00)
 Next
```

There are two interesting moments here:

1. We still need to know actual array size: as you see I used 255 `in` couple of lines
2. Its a good point to use `_` to write this statement in several lines: for example, I wrote data by 16 values in line in hex, so it is easy to read now.

Answer (score 1):

There is no array initialisation syntax in VB6/VBA.

Depending on your needs you can:

Use `Array()` - but this will return an array of *variants*:

```
Dim sbox() As Variant: sbox = Array(&H63, &H7C, &H77, ..., &H7B)
```

**Or** use a helper which will return a strongly typed array:

```
Dim sbox() As Byte: sbox = ByteArray(&H63, &H7C, &H77, ..., &H7B)
 ...
Private Function ByteArray(ParamArray values() As Variant) As Byte()
    ReDim bytes(UBound(values)) As Byte
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(values)
        bytes(i) = values(i)
    Next
    ByteArray = bytes
End Function
```

**Or** dump the raw bytes to a file, include that file as a custom resource (.res/resource add-in) and from then on:

```
Dim sbox() As Byte: sbox = LoadResData(101, "SBOX_VALS")
```

Comment: Thank you for your workaround! Yes, I saw the way of using `As Variant` arrays for my task but I really need to use `As Byte` (I suppose so). But idea of creating `As Variant` and then convert to `As Byte` is really simple and useful!
I will try it. Also want to try solutions with files.
By the way I found one more way, I post answer below. Check it please!

Answer (score 0):

[The answer by Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42553855/3195477) is a good one. I would just add that many times when I have a long repetitive series of programming statements to enter, I usually will create a simple spreadsheet to auto-generate the lines.

i.e., in Excel, put your values in column A, then in column B put `=CONCATENATE(...)` statements to form up the VB6 code. Finally, copy/paste as text into your IDE.

Comment: Thank you! Wow, it's interesting. I didn't knew Excel use VB6 (I thought about VBA).
By the way I found one more way, I post answer below. Check it if you are interesting!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin this cat, though for large Byte arrays a custom resource may make more sense.  Here is one example:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const WIN32_NULL As Long = 0
Private Const WIN32_FALSE As Long = 0

Private Enum CS_FLAGS
    CRYPT_STRING_HEX = &H4&
End Enum

Private Declare Function CryptStringToBinary Lib "Crypt32" _
    Alias "CryptStringToBinaryW" ( _
    ByVal pszString As Long, _
    ByVal cchString As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlags As CS_FLAGS, _
    ByVal pbBinary As Long, _
    ByRef cbBinary As Long, _
    ByVal pdwSkip As Long, _
    ByRef dwFlagsActual As CS_FLAGS) As Long

Private Sub HexToBytes(ByRef HexData As String, ByRef Bytes() As Byte)
    Dim OutLen As Long
    Dim dwActualUsed As CS_FLAGS

    OutLen = UBound(Bytes) - LBound(Bytes) + 1
    If CryptStringToBinary(StrPtr(HexData), _
                           Len(HexData), _
                           CRYPT_STRING_HEX, _
                           VarPtr(Bytes(LBound(Bytes))), _
                           OutLen, _
                           WIN32_NULL, _
                           dwActualUsed) = WIN32_FALSE Then
        Err.Raise &H8004A700, _
                  "HexToBytes", _
                  "CryptStringToBinary failed, error " & CStr(Err.LastDllError)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Const EXAMPLE_ONE As String = "41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48"
    Const EXAMPLE_TWO As String = _
        "4C6F72656D20697073756D20646F6C6F722073697420616D65742C20636F6E73" _
      & "656374657475720D0A61646970697363696E6720656C69742E20557420696E20" _
      & "75726E6120677261766964612C0D0A68656E647265726974206D69206E6F6E2C" _
      & "20666163696C6973697320616E74652E0D0A0D0A41656E65616E20616320656E" _
      & "696D2074656D7075732C206C6163696E69612070757275730D0A717569732C20" _
      & "766F6C75747061742076656C69742E2053757370656E64697373652071756973" _
      & "0D0A636F6D6D6F646F206E6962682E204E616D206574206C696265726F206575" _
      & "206C65637475730D0A73616769747469732072686F6E6375732E2E2E2E2E2E21"
    Dim One(1 To 8) As Byte
    Dim Two(0 To 255) As Byte

    AutoRedraw = True

    HexToBytes EXAMPLE_ONE, One
    Print UBound(One) - LBound(One) + 1; ":"
    Print StrConv(One, vbUnicode)

    HexToBytes EXAMPLE_TWO, Two
    Print UBound(Two) - LBound(Two) + 1; ":"
    Print StrConv(Two, vbUnicode)
End Sub
```

Comment: Bob, thank you very much! Your answer is a bit confusing me - I can't understand all of this just by reading, need to try to code this to see results.
By the way I found one more way, I post answer below. Check it please, I want to know your point of view!